# How to center the page in popup after open bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, popup, bookmarklet

```
javascript:q=location.href;p=document.title;void(open('http://example.page/links/bookmarklet_new?
link%5Burl%5D='+encodeURIComponent(q)+'&link%5Btitle%5D='+encodeURIComponent(p),'Page','toolbar=no,width=700,height=350'));
```

Im using Bookmarklet script like above. But in case if user is not logged he is redirected to root_path. But then I would like to scroll or center page to login form. I tried override styles. But how to check when page is open in popup window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your bookmarklet add a query string parameter like `&view=popup`, then the page you open can check the query parameter and change the HTML or CSS as necessary. If your page redirects, make sure it checks for the `view` parameter and passes it to the next page.

Another option for showing the correct part of the page within the window is to use a hash and a fragment identifier in the url. For example `#loginform`.